# How to set up a dual-boot (OS X and Windows 7/8) environment in a Mac OS X Virtual Machine?

Tags: bootcamp, virtualization, dual-boot

Anyone found a way to set up a dual-boot environment (preferably Mac OS X 10.9 and Windows 7) in a Mac OS X VM using a type-2 hypervisor like Parallels or VMware Fusion with Boot Camp Assistant?

Starting Boot Camp Assistant in a Mac OS X 10.9.5 VM to add a Boot Camp partition just throws an exception:

```
Process:         Boot Camp Assistant [411]
Path:            /Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Boot Camp Assistant
Identifier:      com.apple.bootcampassistant
Version:         5.1.2 (484)
Build Info:      BootCampAssistant-5706000000000000~80
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [266]
Responsible:     Boot Camp Assistant [411]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2015-02-15 12:38:05.984 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8aaae25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff96328e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a98c4f5 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 245
3   Boot Camp Assistant                 0x00000001036fdbd6 Boot Camp Assistant + 76758
4   Boot Camp Assistant                 0x00000001036f9dc8 Boot Camp Assistant + 60872
5   Boot Camp Assistant                 0x00000001036ece71 Boot Camp Assistant + 7793
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a9ce309 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 201
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b71fafd -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1157
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b7145ce loadNib + 327
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b713b6c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 288
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b71395c -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 197
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b71374b +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 357
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b70f597 NSApplicationMain + 448
13  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8b4e85fd start + 1
...
```

I need such an environment for testing purposes and to illustrate or solve Boot Camp related questions here at apple.stackexchange. The spare Mac I used previously died.

Comment: You probably know far more about it than me, but could rEFit be any use for that?

Comment: @Tetsujin Hmmm, i never tried rEFInd in virtual environments. I'm gonna test it immediately...

Comment: Fingers crossed - your Boot Camp/Core Storage posts have been very useful.